# How to resolve firebase build faild error?

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

I tried making a chatapp with firebase, but when i try to run the app on an emulator i get this "Error: Type com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$zza is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkv$3`."

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firebasechat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

check declare plugin in gradle module. and define classpath to project gradle

Comment: plugin is applied and classpath from project gradle file is classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'